# How to compute the backprop of tf.nn.conv2d without using tf.keras.layers.conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to figure out how to backpropagate gradients from `Conv2D`, but `T.gradient` always returns `None`.

I'm using Python 3.7.5 and TensorFlow 2.2.0.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(0, 9, dtype = np.float32).reshape((1, 3, 3, 1))
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), dtype = np.float32).reshape((3, 3, 1, 1))

tf_arr = tf.constant(arr)
tf_kernel = tf.constant(kernel)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True, watch_accessed_variables = True) as T:
    tf_out =  tf.nn.conv2d(tf_arr, tf_kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = "SAME", data_format = 'NHWC')


print(T.gradient(tf_kernel, tf_arr))
```

Comment: I think your indentation is incorrect.